# Cannot read property 'style' of undefined - Javascript .addEventListener()

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm trying to make a game and every time a button is pressed, I want to change the backgroundColor of divs inside a list.

**This is my error message**

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`

**This is my JavaScript**

```
var difficulty;
var btnChosen = document.querySelectorAll("button")
var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square")
var colors = []

for (var i = 0; i < btnChosen.length; i++) {
    btnChosen[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (this.textContent === "Normal") {
            difficulty = 6
            for (var i = 0; i < difficulty; i++) {
                colors[i] = "rbg("+pickRandom(255)+", "+pickRandom(255)+", "+pickRandom(255)+")"
                squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i]
                console.log(colors[i])
                console.log(squares[i])
            }
            console.log(difficulty)
            console.log(colors)
        }
    })
}
```

**This is my HTML**

```
<div>
    <span id="message"></span>
    <button>Normal</button>
</div>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="normal-mode" class="square"></div>
        <div id="normal-mode" class="square"></div>
        <div id="normal-mode" class="square"></div>
        <div id="normal-mode" class="square"></div>
        <div id="normal-mode" class="square"></div>
        <div id="normal-mode" class="square"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `document.querySelectorAll` to `document.querySelector`. You don't have to use `document.querySelectorAll` since it is only one button. It will be ideal to give the button element an id. Thus `<button id="id-here">Some text</button>` and reference it using `document.querySelector("#id-here")`. Change remove `btnChosen[i]` to `btnChosen` because the variable only contains one element not many.

Get rid of `for (var i = 0; i < btnChosen.length; i++)`. It is not needed.